# environment variables for non interactive bash shells

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, unix

We have a non-interactive bash shell command which executes some code and that code reads some environment variables.

```
 #!/bin/bash 
  export PATH="/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib/ambari-server/*:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/var/lib/ambari-agent"
    export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf"}
    export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME:-"/usr/java/default"}
    export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
    export NM_HOST="test.com"
    export LOGNAME="root"
    export JVM_PID="$$"
    export PWD="/opt/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002"
    export LOCAL_DIRS="/opt/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1504729685201_0003"
    export SHDP_CONTAINERID="container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002"
    export NM_HTTP_PORT="8042"
    export LOG_DIRS="/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002"
    export NM_AUX_SERVICE_mapreduce_shuffle="AAA0+gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
    "
    export NM_PORT="45454"
    export USER="root"
    export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_YARN_HOME:-"/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-nodemanager"}
    export CLASSPATH="/org/test/import/application.yml:./*"
    export HADOOP_TOKEN_FILE_LOCATION="/opt/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/container_tokens"
    export NM_AUX_SERVICE_spark_shuffle=""
    export LOCAL_USER_DIRS="/opt/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/"
    export HADOOP_HOME="/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/hadoop"
    export HOME="/home/"
    export NM_AUX_SERVICE_spark2_shuffle=""
    export CONTAINER_ID="container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002"
    export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX="4"
    ln -sf "/opt/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1504729685201_0003/filecache/11/application.yml" "application.yml"
    hadoop_shell_errorcode=$?
    if [ $hadoop_shell_errorcode -ne 0 ]
    then
      exit $hadoop_shell_errorcode
    fi
    ln -sf "/opt/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1504729685201_0003/filecache/12/test.jar" "test.jar"
    hadoop_shell_errorcode=$?
    if [ $hadoop_shell_errorcode -ne 0 ]
    then
      exit $hadoop_shell_errorcode
    fi
    # Creating copy of launch script
    cp "launch_container.sh" "/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/launch_container.sh"
    chmod 640 "/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/launch_container.sh"
    # Determining directory contents
    echo "ls -l:" 1>"/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/directory.info"
    ls -l 1>>"/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/directory.info"
    echo "find -L . -maxdepth 5 -ls:" 1>>"/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/directory.info"
    find -L . -maxdepth 5 -ls 1>>"/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/directory.info"
    echo "broken symlinks(find -L . -maxdepth 5 -type l -ls):" 1>>"/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/directory.info"
    find -L . -maxdepth 5 -type l -ls 1>>"/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/directory.info"

    exec /bin/bash -c "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar test.jar  1>/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/Container.stdout 2>/opt/hadoop/yarn/log/application_1504729685201_0003/container_e11_1504729685201_0003_01_000002/Container.stderr"
    hadoop_shell_errorcode=$?
    if [ $hadoop_shell_errorcode -ne 0 ]
    then
      exit $hadoop_shell_errorcode
```

we added environment variables needed by code in ~/.bashrc file, but it seems non-interactive shells don't read this file so our code was not able to get required env variables. Unfortunately the bash script that I am using is auto generated and I can't export my env variables there. Is there any other way to make the env variables available for our java code?  Thanks.

Comment: You are correct that a non-interactive shell does not source `.bashrc`. How do you actually run the script?

Comment: Unrelated, but the call to `/bin/bash` doesn't seem necessary. `exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" -jar test.jar` would work as well.

Comment: Actually that entire code is in a .sh file and this file is auto generated and executed by spring yarn framework.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that framework, but I would be very surprised if it didn't provide a way to specify the environment for a command that it will execute.

Comment: Asking the same question again because [the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095310/how-to-make-environment-variables-available-for-non-interactive-bash-shells?noredirect=1#comment79152551_46095310) was closed and  you don't agree with the closure is not an option. The proper way is to vote for it's reopening.

Comment: The framework is putting most of the env vars required in the .sh file as you can see, but our code requires some other env vars and they must be read from existing env variables and should not be put in this .sh file due to security reasons.

Comment: @RC  Well, with due respect, closing the question as duplicate when it is not actually a duplicate in any way is also not correct. Also people in general don't respond to questions which are marked as duplicate and here I require some quick help.

Comment: The fact is that there are rules and the rule is if your question is close-voted as duplicate then it is unless the required amount of reopen vote are cast (*dura lex, sed lex*). I could close this as a duplicate of the old one, but I will not. Note that next time (if there is a next time) I will seek moderator attention)

Comment: Regarding your question, see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101620/how-to-load-bashrc-from-bash-c/101638

Answer (score 0):

Specifically required environment variables can be configured in /etc/hadoop/conf/yarn-site.xml, there is a property there, yarn.nodemanager.admin-env that is used to list environment variables that should be forwarded from the NodeManager's environment to the container's.
By default the value is MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=$MALLOC_ARENA_MAX, you just need to append a comma separated list with the variables you need to pass:
e.g.
MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=$MALLOC_ARENA_MAX,YOUR_VARIABLE=$YOUR_VARIABLE

This can also be configured with Ambari in the Yarn-site advanced configuration section for yarn.

Is a good practice to use a script in /etc/profile.d/ to setup global environment variables, available for all users.

References:
- Yarn site default configuration
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.11/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml

- EnvironmentVariables #System-wide environment variables section
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables